# How to control 80 outputs using 1 PLC?

Tags: digital-logic, relay

I am new to PLCs. I'm currently working on a project which requires me to control 80 outputs (small pumps) with one PLC. Can anyone tell me if this is possible? Do I need 80 inputs to control each one independently? I have a Vigor VS1-32MR. The end goal is also to control the PLC using a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: 8 bit serial address with data ought to handle that. 7a+1d, with parity and feedback confirmation

Comment: You must read/follow the OEM’s protocol

Comment: If you intend to control 80 outputs with the Vigor PLC, you have to use the Vigor expansion modules to get more outputs. At first I thought you wanted to control 80 outputs with a "pic" controller, for which the answer by @mkeith is correct. What is the role of the R-pi? Via USB to the PLC?

Comment: I read pic, too. I guess I made a mistake. My apologies.

Comment: so theres no way to control them without increasing the number or outputs?  R-pi is to control the PLC remotely with 4g. Please feel free to recommend any alternative way of achieving this. Im very very new to this so idek what works and what doesn't

Comment: Not much info provided. We can’t tell you how many inputs you might need without any information about the application. You can’t independently control 80 pumps with less than 80 outputs unless you start adding additional components, if that’s what you’re asking. There are endless numbers of ways to do this with additional components, but you give no criteria.

Comment: "*do i need 80 inputs to control each one ...*" No. You need 80 **outputs**.

Comment: I'd be looking towards using 8 small PLCs with 10 outputs or 10 PLCs with 8 outputs or so on. I'd hate to replace one PLC and have to rewire 80 outputs! You can then connect the PLCs via RS485/Modbus (or similar) and talk to them via the RasPi with a usb->RS485 adapter. A RasPI wouldn't be my first choice - they're not really suited to industrial usage.

Comment: sorry for the lack of info guys, I'm trying to make a water sampling system with 80 bottles to collect water from the river. im using a pixhawk with a raspberry pi and some thrusters to control the boat over 4g, was hoping I would be able to control the plc with the raspberry pi I already have on the boat.

Comment: So each pump draws a water sample from the same point and pumps to its own sample bottle? Will you ever take more than one sample at a time? Will you always take samples in the same order?

Comment: @Pat each pump takes water from different points say 80 or maybe 50 different points on the river and but yeah in the same order 1,2,3...80.

Comment: could i make a 7 Bit relay logic to choose between the 80 or 128 i guess bottles?

Answer (score 0):

The question relates to the minimum number of inputs required for manual on/off control of 80 pumps in a simple PLC application.

To save on the number of inputs, two standard thumbwheel switches, with BCD output, may be used to input the pump number.

Alternatively a 2 digit up/down counter, with 7 segment display, BCD output and up/down scroll buttons, could be used.

The number of inputs required would be 11 (1 to select 'manual operation', 8 for BCD input and  1 each for 'pump start' and 'pump stop').